# Why isn't my binary search returning the name to display?

Tags: c++

Sorry, but I cannot figure out why my code but more specifically the binary searchName() function is not returning the name to display. I have verified the names are sorted with the display function which isn't required for the assignment. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code start to end. We haven't covered vectors or anything further than arrays so vectors won't help, but I can't wait until we do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//function Prototypes
void nameSort(string friendArray[], int ARRAY_SIZE);
//function to display names from file
void displayNames(string friendArray[], int counter);
//function to binary search for name in file/array 
//How do i return a string?? I got the following code from web searches
int searchName(string friendArray[], int ARRAY_SIZE, string result);

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 200; //declare array size
    string friendArray[ARRAY_SIZE];//array of 200 strings
    ifstream fileIn; //create file object

    int counter = 0;
    string choice;
    string result; //variable to hold the search result

    fileIn.open("myFriends.dat");//open the file
    if(fileIn.fail())//test to see if file opened
    {
        cout<<"Check to see if file is in same directory ";
        cout<<"as the .cpp file."<<endl;
    }

    while(getline(fileIn, friendArray[counter]))
    {
        counter++;
    }

    //call function to sort array
    nameSort(friendArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    //display sorted names to screen with function
    displayNames(friendArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    //call to search function
    searchName(friendArray, ARRAY_SIZE, result);
    cout<<friendArray[]<<" is my friend."<<endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

//sort function
void  nameSort(string friendArray[], const int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    bool swap;
    string temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false; //set flag to false
        for(int counter = 0; counter < (ARRAY_SIZE - 1); counter++)
        {
            if(friendArray[counter] > friendArray[counter + 1])
            {
                temp = friendArray[counter];
                friendArray[counter] = friendArray[counter + 1];
                friendArray[counter + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }//close for loop
    }while(swap);
}//end of function

//display names function

void displayNames(string friendArray[], const int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
        cout<<friendArray[index]<<endl;
}

//binary search function
int searchName(string friendArray[], const int ARRAY_SIZE, string result)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = (ARRAY_SIZE - 1);
    int middle;
    int position = -1;
    string name;
    bool found = false;

    cout<<"Please enter a name or END to quit.";
    cin>>name;

    while(!found && first <= last && name != "END")
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;

        if(friendArray[middle] == result)
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if(friendArray[middle] > result)
            last = (middle - 1);
        else 
            first = (middle + 1);
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't? You're not using the return value of searchName in your output.

Comment: Unrelated: kindly fix `int main` to be `int main()`. And I'm trying to guess what you're trying to do with `cout<<friendArray[]`.

Comment: A comment on that binary search you found: benchmarking usually shows that the !found and if middle == result comparisons slow down the algorithm over simply adjusting last and first until they're equal. Then you check for the match once at the end. But get it working before you get fancy. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Rup is correct. Try changing your code to

```
int friendIndex = searchName(friendArray, ARRAY_SIZE, result);
cout<<friendArray[friendIndex]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
```

I forgot that you should check for friendIndex == -1 first. This would be better:

```
int friendIndex = searchName(friendArray, ARRAY_SIZE, result);
if(friendIndex >= 0)
    cout<<friendArray[friendIndex]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
else
    cout<<result<<" is not my friend."<<endl;
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand a little better. I should create/initialize a variable to hold the output of the search with the friendIndex? Followed your comments but still received weird output. The output is actually supposed to display to the screen for example: "Jim Jones is my friend." If not a friend "Name of friend is not my friend." Should I have prompts for user input in the binary function or should this be moved elsewhere like the main? I've never quite understood that and was led to believe functions should do calculations etc..thank you.

Comment: @allendks45: The search function should take a parameter to tell it what to look for. I thought this was the result string, but apparently I missed that in my reading. Change it to ask for the name of the friend in main() and pass that into searchName.